# How to characterize distribution of random variable $Z = (1-X)Y_1 + XY_2$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Z$ be a random variable and $Z = (1-X)Y_1 + XY_2$. $X \sim \text{U}(0,1)$, and $Y_1,\, Y_2 \sim f$. Assume that $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are all independent.

I tried to find some tips online for finding the PDF, but didn't find anything relevant. Manipulation doesn't seem to be easy.

My guess is that it may be very difficult to get something analytic. If this is the case, then what can I do to characterize the distribution? I am thinking of parametric simulations for specific distribution functions $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a random mixture model with uniform mixture density.  Suppose $Y_1, Y_2$ are IID with common density $f_Y$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Z \le z] 
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[(1-x)Y_1 + xY_2 \le z] f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[(1-x)Y_1 + xY_2 \le z] \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y_2\in\Omega_Y} F_Y\left(\frac{z - xy_2}{1-x}\right) f_Y(y_2) \, dy_2
\end{align}$$ since $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.  Unfortunately, we cannot always get a nice closed form solution for this integral.  For instance, if $Y_1, Y_2 \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$, then the conditional distribution of $Z \mid X = (1-X)Y_1 + X Y_2 \mid X$ has density $$f_{Z \mid X}(z) = \frac{\lambda }{1-2x}\left(e^{-\frac{\lambda z}{1-x}}-e^{-\frac{\lambda z}{x}}\right)$$ but the unconditional/marginal density for $Z$ is problematic to evaluate.  We run into similar difficulties if $Y_1, Y_2$ are standard normal.  I leave an open-ended question as to whether one can think of any nontrivial parametric families for the $Y_i$ that yield a nice closed form solution for the marginal density of $Z$.

That is not to say we cannot get moments of $Z$; e.g., by the laws of total expectation and variance, if $Y_1, Y_2$ have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, we easily calculate
$$\operatorname{E}[Z] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(1-X)Y_1 + X Y_2 \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[(1-X)\operatorname{E}[Y_1] + X \operatorname{E}[Y_2]] = \operatorname{E}[(1-X)\mu + X \mu] = \operatorname{E}[\mu] = \mu,$$ and
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[Z] &= \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[(1-X)Y_1 + X Y_2 \mid X]] + \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[(1-X)Y_1 + X Y_2 \mid X]] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[\mu] + \operatorname{E}[(1-X)^2 \sigma^2 + X^2 \sigma^2] \\
&= \sigma^2 \operatorname{E}[1-2X + 2X^2] \\
&= \frac{2}{3}\sigma^2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I've ran some simulations previously, and that 2/3 factor in front of the variance is spot on!

Comment: @heropup Curious how you got that 3rd line in the first equation.

Comment: @KaiserHaz: Using independence of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and total probability yields $$\mathbb P\{Y_1+Y_2\leq z\}=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{Y_1\leq z-y\}f(y)\,\mathrm d y.$$ I let you adapt this to your situation.

Comment: How was the first line of the variance calculation obtained?

Comment: @KaiserHaz The law of total variance states $$\operatorname{Var}[B] = \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[B \mid A]] + \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[B \mid A]].$$  Conditioned on $X$, the expectation of $Z \mid X$ is $\mu$ as we calculated earlier.  The variance of $Z \mid X$ is computed using the independence of $Y_1, Y_2$ and the formula $\operatorname{Var}[aY] = a^2 \operatorname{Var}[Y]$ for a scalar $a$.

Comment: If one considers $X$ uniform on $[0; \frac{3}{2}]$, then the variance of $Z$ equals $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

It's no clear in your statement if $X$ and $Y_i$ are independents for all $i$ or if $X,Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. I'll suppose that $X,Y_1,Y_2$ are independents. According to Total probability,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{Z\leq z\}&=\int_{0}^1\mathbb P\{(1-x)Y_1+xY_2\leq z\mid X=x\}dx\\
&=\int_0^1\mathbb P\{(1-x)Y_1+xY_2\leq z\}dx,
\end{align}
where the last equality comes from the fact that $X$ is independent of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. I let you conclude.